# Would you give me a clue to prove this differential equation converge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(I'm not good at English, so please tell me if you can not understand my expression. I will revise it.)

When I solves the past problem for exam of graduate school, I'm struguling to solve one problem. I've been thinking for somedays, but I can not come up with even the plan to solve.

This is the problem.

> (1) find $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}$

> (2) when f(x) is differentable in $x \ge 1$, and $$f(1) = 1$$
> $$ { f'(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{f(x)} + 1} ( \frac{1}{x^2 + f(x)^2} )^2 }, x \ge 1 $$
> prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ converges to finte value

> (3) prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) < \frac{5}{4}$

problem (1) is easy. By using $x = \tan \theta$, I found $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2} = \frac{1}{8}(\pi - 2)$

But I completely have no idea to solve (2), (3).

Once I have suspecetd that Laplace's final value theorem or l'Hôpital's rule is available.

But it dosen't work.

Honestly, I am not sure whether this is the problem about differential equation or not.

So would you give me a hint or some theorem to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the $f(x) \geq 1$, since it starts at $1$ and is increasing. Hence $$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{f(x)} + 1} \left( \frac{1}{x^2 + f(x)^2} \right)^2 \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{1}+1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1^2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Thus, $f$ is bounded above by the solution to the IVP
$$ y'(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}, \  y(1)=1$$

So that $y(x) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$. But we can solve that IVP by direct integration to see that $$ f(x) \leq y(x) = 1 + \int_1^x \frac{1}{(t^2+1)^2} \ \text{d}t$$

And since that integral converges, $y(x)$ approaches some finite limit. Furthermore, we know that $f(x)$, besides being bounded above by $y$, is bounded below by $0$, and has positive derivative for $x \geq 1$, so is increasing. Hence, $f$ converges to some finite limit.

And, indeed, that limit is bounded above by the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ of $y$.

We have $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(t^2+1)^2}\text{d}t = 1 + \frac{\pi-2}{8} \approx 1.142 < 1.25 = \frac{5}{4}$$

Giving the desired bound on the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!